# composer install composer/package-versions-deprecated : Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known

Tags: continuous-integration, composer-php, gitlab-ci, symfony4, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a symfony4 app in cloudfoundry. I got an error with "composer/package-versions-deprecated":

- Auto deploy(with gitlab-ci): I get this error below:
  [image: sy]

The same Error with cli local deploy(cf push)

composer.json:

```
 "minimum-stability": "beta",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
   .......
    {
      "packagist": false
    },
    ...
  ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.10",
...
```

**PHP version**: 7.2; **Symfony**: 4.4.9; **Composer Version**: 1.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused by dist-Url(not authorized directly) in composer-lock.json

it fixed by changing the URL: private repository under api.github:

```
"dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://privateRepo... /api/composer/php-proxy-official/vcs-dists/zip/doctrine/reflection/55e71912dfcd824b2fdd16f2d9afe15684cfce79",
                "reference": "55e71912dfcd824b2fdd16f2d9afe15684cfce79",
                "shasum": ""
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a network problem. It's saying that Composer cannot resolve the DNS address for github.com.

This could be a temporary problem, like if Github is having issues, but that's unlikely. What's more probable is that your Cloud Foundry operators have restricted access to the Internet. Perhaps through Application Security Groups, which is something that only an Operator with "admin" permissions can adjust.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/asg.html

The other possibility is that you can access the Internet but you must do so through a proxy. You would need to confirm with your Operators if this is true and if so, what proxy information you'd need to use. If, and it is solely up to your Platform Operations team, you can access the Internet through a proxy then your Ops team would need to configure it. They can do that globally with these instructions.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/proxy-usage.html

or you can do the same thing with `cf set-env` on a per-application basis.